# How to integrate LDAP and Strong loop gateway OAuth system?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, ldap, strongloop

I have designed a solution to replace OAuth Authentication system with LDAP system. i am writing this blog as this would be helpful for other developers while using strong loop OAuth Tool with some other Authentication system.

Majorly, I did changes in library file of project "loopback-component-oauth2", which located in strong-gateway package.

```
Location of file: loopback-component-oauth2\lib
file name: oauth2-loopback.js
Method: userLogin
Signature: req, res, callback
```

Below code explain how to change method "userLogin" defination:

```
function userLogin(req, res, next) {

    var OPTS = {
        server: { 
            url:   '<>',
                bindDn:   'CN=<>,CN=<>,DC=<>,DC=<>,DC=<>',
                bindCredentials:   '<>',
                searchBase:   'DC=<>,DC=<>,DC=<>',
                searchFilter:   '(<>={{<>}})'
        }
    };

    var app = express();
    passport.use(new LdapStrategy(OPTS));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: false
    }));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    passport.authenticate('ldapauth', {
        session: false
    }, function(err, user, req) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err); // will generate a 500 error
        }
        // Generate a JSON response reflecting authentication status
        if (!user) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return next(null, user);
        }
    })(req, res, next);      
}
```